# How to separate contents of item containers?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am in the process of building an email scraper and am having trouble when it comes to yielding items. My yield prints as:

```
{'email': ['ex1@email.com', 'ex2@email.com', 'ex3@email.com']}
```

Whenever I export this into CSV I have an email header and then the three emails are listed in the same cell. How would I separate these into individual cells?

```
class EmailSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'emails'
    start_urls = ['https://example.com']

    parsed_url = urlparse(start_urls[0])
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow_domains=parsed_url), callback='parse', follow=True)]

    def parse(self, response):
        # Scrape page for email links
        items = EmailscrapeItem()

        hrefs = [response.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()").getall()]
        # Removes hrefs that are empty or None
        hrefs = [d for d in hrefs if d]
        # TODO: Add code to capture non-mailto emails as well
        # hrefs.append(response.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '@')]/text()"))

        for href in hrefs:
            items['email'] = href
            yield items
```

Comment: How are you exporting to CSV?

Comment: Is parse function part of a larger code? Can you share that too in the question by editing it?

Comment: By using command line tool: scrapy crawl emails -o emails.csv

Comment: Added the rest of the spider as well

Comment: to have in separated rows you should use `for`-loop to `yield` every email separatelly. To have in separated columns you would have to yield `{'email1': 'ex1@email.com', 'email2': 'ex2@email.com', 'email3': 'ex3@email.com'}` and this will create columns `email1`, `email2`, `email3`

Comment: This would create individual items for each email correct? How would I instead create individual rows for item 'emails'?   Current for loop I have at bottom of code stores emails in item 'emails' as a list, however I don't know how to separate the list itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what I did wrong.

I changed my parse to:

```
        for res in response.xpath("//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/text()"):
            item = EmailscrapeItem()
            item['email'] = res.get()
            yield item
```

This yielded the proper results.